# Azure Mobile Services PullAsync not all data

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Using Azure Mobile Services and Azure Easy Tables on the back end I want to get filtered data on the client since tables could be quite large but useful rows to specific user with own ID wouldn't be. I tried to use

```
IMobileServiceTableQuery<Messages> query = 
    msgTable.Where(c => c.UserId==_myId);

await msgTable.PullAsync("syncmsg"+_myid, query);
```

but it turns out that PullAsync apply query only on next times but first time it pulls all data. It there any way using Azure Mobile Services pull and store on local storage only filtered on query data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, first things first - you should do security filtering on the server, not the client.  There are easy ways to adjust the filter on the server for your specifications.  See https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples for plenty of samples.

As to this issue, you are building the query wrong.  The thing you want is:

```
var query = msgTable.CreateQuery().Where(c => c.UserId == myId);
await msgTable.PullAsync('mysyncquery', query);
```

Note the CreateQuery() in the middle.  Without that, you don't get the base query set up.

Comment: Thanks for correction. But it still returns all rows. So the only way is to write filters on server side and I can't pass query from client side with all filters?

Comment: Take a look at the query that is being passed to the backend.  It should include $filter=(userId eq 'something') -- this should work, and my tests indicate the right thing happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Unfortunately I can't say what was the problem for others who might get stuck on the same but now it started to work!

Comment: @AdrianHall can you give an example how to use this filter? I don't know how to do that, but I have the same problem.