# Filter data from azure database using Mobile Service client

Tags: forms, azure, xamarin, mobile, service

I am trying to restrict the data returned by the Mobile App service hosted on Azure portal. Unfortunately I am unable to restrict the data before it's returned (at the createQuery() stage). The filter works only when applied after the data is returned. Here is a sample code. The app is written in Xamarin forms on iOS platform.

```
     public async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> GetCompanies(string  
                                      cityId)
     {
        await App.MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, 
                         handler);
        this.companies = App.MobileService.GetSyncTable<Company>();

        try
        {
            await App.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();

            // Filter is unsuccessful here
            await this.companies.PullAsync("all_companies", 
              this.companies.CreateQuery().Where(x => x.City_Id ==  
                    cityId)).ConfigureAwait(false);
          }
          catch (MobileServicePushFailedException ex)
          {
               string ErrorString = string.Format("Push failed because 
                 of Company sync errors: {0} errors, message: 
                  {1}",ex.PushResult.Errors.Count, ex.Message);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Debug.WriteLine("Exception Sync companies: " + ex);
            }
             // Filter works here. But its too late as it has already
             // pulled all the unnecessary data
             return await companies.Where(x => x.City_Id == 
               cityId).OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToEnumerableAsync();
       }
```

Comment: Here is a similar case maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766740/azure-mobile-services-pullasync-not-all-data

Comment: I had looked into that however, it doesn't work. Hence, I created a new thread.